# Как нормируется разговорный стиль на письме?

Tags: стили-речи

**Разговорный стиль** – это особый функциональный стиль со своей лексикой и  грамматикой. Вот, например, информация из Сети на эту тему: https://pandia.ru/text/80/185/53511-3.php

Разговорный стиль  используется в основном в устной речи, но **с отдельными элементами** его приходится сталкиваться и в письменных текстах.

К тому же бывает **трудно обозначить границу** между нейтральным и разговорным стилем, да и запись речи персонажей в художественных произведениях требует соблюдения каких-то правил.

Меня интересует, **где найти самые общие практические сведения** по оформлению и грамматическому анализу разговорной речи или ее отдельных элементов (особенно не углубляясь в тему), есть ли  хотя бы **отдельные указания в общих правилах письма** (ПАС, Розенталь, Грамота.ру).

И конкретные примеры: **(1) Скажите, вы устали? (2) Можно я задам вопрос?**

**Как определить вид этих предложений** и можно ли это точно сделать (мне они кажутся гибридами стандартного синтаксиса)?  **Как объяснить** постановку или отсутствие запятой?

Comment: По поводу знаков препинания, см. у Розенталя. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=198#pp198

Comment: Да, спасибо, правда, это уже совсем разговорные конструкции. А вот предложения, похожие на  приведенные  (1) и (2), Розенталь где-нибудь в общих правилах упоминает?

Comment: К сожалению, приведенные примеры Розенталь нигде не упоминает. Но по поводу нашего предложения, я задал вопрос лингвистам СПб института, и один из них ответил. В принципе он написал то же, что и я, только в отличии от меня, он говорит, для трансформации этого предложения в СПП, нужно добавить союз-частицу ли

Comment: А для этого, вы сами понимаете, нужно изменить порядок слов

Comment: Серж, я спрашиваю про предложение "скажите, вы устали?". Что я там могу изменить и куда частицу ЛИ употребить? А вопрос тот же: вид синтаксической конструкции можно определить?  Такое предложение относится к нейтральному или разговорному стилю, оно где-нибудь разбирается?

Comment: Я говорил о том предложении, с которого началась дискуссия.

Comment: Думаю,это нейтральный стиль.